# In wso2 ESB 4.8 salseforce connector getting read time out while invoking that service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In wso2 ESB 4.8 salseforce connector getting read time out while invoking that service from SOAPUI.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"  name="salseforce_queryservice"
   transports="https http"
   startOnLoad="true"
   trace="enable"><target> <inSequence>         <salesforce.init>
        <username>XXXXX</username>
        <password>******</password>
        <loginUrl>https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/29.0</loginUrl>
     </salesforce.init>
     <salesforce.query>
        <batchSize>200</batchSize>
        <queryString>SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Account.Name FROM Contact</queryString>
     </salesforce.query>
     <respond/>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence/>
  <faultSequence/> </target> </proxy>
```

Comment: What are the errors you see in wso2carbon.log?

Comment: The error i'm getting in wso2carbon.log is  'Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://172.26.9.150:8280/services/Query_salseforce_sample.Query_salseforce_sampleHttpSoap12Endpoint] {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender}
org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException: The server 172.26.9.150 failed to respond

Answer (score 0):

There is an error while executing this. Try using a fault sequence in the proxy and check the error from fault sequence. EG: add onError="fault" to proxy.

Looking to this most likely this may be a login issue. Did you append the security token to password?

Best Regards,
Malaka

Comment: Yes i have appended the security token to the password.

Comment: I am getting a fault string as 'No operation available for request {urn:partner.soap.sforce.com}login'

Comment: as u said there is a mistake in login only not the password its the url https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/29.0 instead of this if i use partner url >https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0 i can connect but when i use Enterprise url like i use i'm getting Read time out error. Thanks in advance

Comment: When i load my wsdl in SOAPUI and try with the same login through https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/29.0 its working but when i use https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0 in SOAPUI i'm getting the same fault whick i got in wso2. Why connector is not able to login through Enterprise URL ????

Comment: The connector appears to be built on the Partner API. This makes sense, as the Partner API is generic and can be used with any Salesforce Org.The Enterprise WSDL, in contrast, is specific to the Org that generated it. This isn't suitable for a generic API wrapper as it contains objects that may only exist in one Salesforce Org.